# Restarting Nagios Using PHP

Tags: php, nagios

I am making a tool that is interacting with NAGIOS where some config files should be added so a restart will be needed.

What I need to know is how to restart NAGIOS using PHP code since this tool is written in PHP .. when I try to do this using:

```
  shell_exec("service nagios restart");
```

changes do not take place but when I do this manually by the console all changes I did using the PHP script are applied ... after 2 minutes research I found that I am asking linux to execut this command while I am logged in as **apache** user so I changed the command to:

```
  shell_exec('echo "mypass" | sudo -S service nagios restart');
```

still having the same problem ... new config files are not read until I restart **manually**

any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: What is returned by shell_exec ? `$output = shell_exec("service nagios restart"); echo "<pre>$output</pre>";`

Comment: @lain it returns what should be returned as if  I'm restarting manually :S

Comment: Running configuration check...done. Stopping nagios: .done. Starting nagios: done

Comment: FYI: You should not restart nagios when the conf changes; just 'reload' is fine. (e.g. SIGHUP)

Comment: @Keith how to do this reload ?? I mean in PHP ??

Comment: "service nagios reload", i'm guessing? or figure out how to send a sighup via PHP (no idea how)

Comment: @AhmadHajjar Have you found answer for this? can you please post it to help others?

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to add your web server to sudoers to enable it from restarting nagios service without being prompted for a password. This will be safer than typing the password in a PHP file. To so it, type:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Then, add a line lik this:

```
apache_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

This will enable `apache_user` to execute only `/path/to/script` with `sudo` privileges with being prompted for a password.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed ... when I execute this command in PHP **echo shell_exec('echo "nagiosxi" | sudo -S service nagios restart');** it echos nothing

Comment: If you added apache user to sudoers file, you need to execute it like: `shell_exec("sudo service nagios restart");`. No need for `echo password` part.

Comment: **echo shell_exec('sudo service nagios restart');** is not printing anything as well :(

Comment: The line you added to the sudoers file had the proper path to the `service` command? Is the user correct? Could you post the line you added?

Comment: I added this line :

`apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/service`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is still something wrong with the permissions, log in as the apache user with `su apacheusername` and then execute your command

```
echo "nagiosxi" | sudo -S service nagios restart
```

to verify this does not give any errors. Are you sure that you are running Nagios as a service?

Comment: when I try to execute this command **su apache** it gives me : *this account is currently not available*

Comment: but is apache your webserver user? In Debian it's www-data.

Comment: yes it is ... when I execute `whoami` in `shell_exec` in PHP it gives me apache